# JBoss 7.1.1 Webservice programatic JAAS authentication

Tags: web-services, authentication, jboss, jboss7.x, jaas

I have a simple POJO as a webservice that is mapped to, lets say /public/authenticate :

```
 WebService
 @SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
 public class AuthWS{

   @WebMethod
   public boolean doAuthenticate(String securityToken) {
    ....
   }
}
```

This webservice doesn't requre authentication and is not a protected resource.

I do have other private webservices mapped to path : /private/ws/*;

For the moment I use a security-domain that has a Database login module setup. It works fine, but user first needs to authenticate trought a web form based that makes a post request to /j_security_check. Only after this step user can use other private webservices.

I want to perform a programatically authentication after client calls this doAuthenticate method. So that client to be able to invoke other /private/ws/* webservice methods.

I'll type what I want to achieve:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public class AuthWS{

@WebMethod
public boolean doAuthenticate(String securityToken) {
      SomeSecurityManager manager= SomeSecurityManager.getDefaultManager()
      Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      map.put("MY_CUSTOM_SECURITY_TOKEN",securityToken);
      manager.doLogin(map);
    // after webservice method returns, client should now be able to invoke other private webservice
    // this means that the manager should associate with this session an authenticated user.
    // in order that authorization to work.
  }
}
```

And my CustomLoginModule :

```
class CustomLogModule implements LoginModule {

  ...
   public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {
       // store what's needed
   } 


  public boolean login(){ 
    // get securityToken send from the SomeSecurityManager and validate it.
    // get user information from that token and store into Subject object.
  } 
}
```

And in my CustomLoginModule that implements JAAS LoginModule to check that securityToken with a custom logic, verify if it right signed with a public key for example. That securityToken contains information about principal.

If you need more details, feel free to ask.

Thanks.

**EDITED**

1.) Created custom-login-module.jar together with module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="custom.login.module">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="custom-login-module.jar"/>
    </resources>


    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.picketbox"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

2.) Added custom-login-module.jar and module.xml into jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\custom\login\module

3.) custom-login-module.jar contains :
    public class CustomCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {

```
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomCallbackHandler.class);
    private String token;

    public CustomCallbackHandler(String token) {
        this.token= token;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (Callback callback : callbacks) {
            if (callback instanceof TokenCallback) {
                ((TokenCallback) callback).setToken(token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TokenCallback implements Callback {
 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenCallback.class);
 private String token;

 public TokenCallback() {
 }

 public String getToken() {
     return token;
 }

 public void setToken(String token) {
     LOGGER.info("Setting token = " + token);
     this.token = token;
 }
}
```

---

```
public class CustomLoginModule extends AbstractServerLoginModule {
 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomLoginModule.class);

 @Override
 public boolean login() throws LoginException {
     LOGGER.info("Doing login()");
     boolean login = super.login();
     super.loginOk = true;
     return login;
 }

 @Override
 protected Principal getIdentity() {
     return new UserPrincipal("some user");
 }

 @Override
 protected Group[] getRoleSets() throws LoginException {
     return new Group[]{new MyGroup()}; // that and has name 'dummy'
 }
}
```

These are only dummy implementations.

My web application is deployed from within  a .war archive. And it Contains following :
jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web
    PUBLIC -//JBoss//DTD Web Application 2.3V2//EN
    http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_3_2.dtd>
 <jboss-web>
    <security-domain>custom-auth</security-domain>
 </jboss-web>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>WebApp</display-name>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
           <description>Protects all private resources</description>
           <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>dummy</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>dummy</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Private</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.private.PrivateWs</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Private</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/private/PrivateWs</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AuthWS</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.auth.AuthWS</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AuthWS</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/AuthWS</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public class AuthWS{
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthWS.class);


@WebMethod
public boolean doAuthenticate(String token) {
    tryProgrammaticLogin(token);
    return true;
}


private void tryProgrammaticLogin(String token) {
    LoginContext loginContext = null;
    try {
        loginContext = new LoginContext("custom-auth", new CustomCallbackHandler(token));
        loginContext.login();
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Some problem occured when trying to custom login.", e);
    }
}
}
```

The call to doAuthenticate from my ws client works but the problem is that after try ProgrammaticLogin an exception occurs. And the PrivateWS is not accesible by client.

```
17:33:40,901 INFO  [com.mycompany.AuthWS] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Some problem occured when trying to custom login.: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Login Failure: all modules ignored
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:921) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
```

standalone.xml from jboss configuration directory contains:

```
<security-domain name="custom-auth">
    <authentication>
         <login-module code="com.mycompany.CustomLoginModule" flag="required" module="custom.login.module"/>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Please tell me if the way of doing authentication with creating a new LoginContext  object is the right way of doing. I can't understand why this problem occurs.